# Chrome Extensions containing puppeteer script

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

Is it possible to create a chrome extension , containing a puppeteer script to scrape and do some browser automation.

I would like to create one where a user would enter a url click a button then a puppeteer script runs, is this possible if so what would be the best way to implement?

Seen some answers referring to puppeteer-web, but seems the Puppeteer team removed puppeteer-web, is there a new way of implementing this?